# "Model class myproject.models.MyModel doesn't declare an explicit app_label during" During Django test

Tags: django, unit-testing, django-testing

With Django 2.2.9 I'm getting the following error when I try to run `./manage test`

```
File "/home/simernes/workspace/myproject/myapp/test/test_functions.py", line 3, in <module>
    from ..functions import make_response
File "/home/simernes/workspace/myproject/myapp/functions.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .serializers import MyModelSerializer, \
File "/home/simernes/workspace/myproject/myapp/serializers.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .models import MyModel, \
File "/home/simernes/workspace/myproject/myapp/models.py", line 7, in <module>
    class MyModel(models.Model):
File "/home/simernes/workspace/myproject/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 111, in __new__
    "INSTALLED_APPS." % (module, name)
RuntimeError: Model class myproject.myapp.models.MyModel doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS.
```

in functions I'm importing the model as follows:

**functions.py:**

```
from .models import MyModel

def make_response():
    print("lorem ipsum")
```

It appears that simply by importing something from the file containing a class extending Model this error occurs, because it happens with the following test definition:

```
from django.test import TestCase
from ..functions import make_response


class MyTestCase(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        pass

    def test_make_response(self):
        self.assertTrue(True)
```

Is there any way to solve this?

**Installed apps:**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'django_filters',
    'corsheaders',
    'myapp',
]
```

Comment: Likely `..functions` imports `.models`? You can not immediately import `models.py` yourself. You should let Django first load the apps in a specific order.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem please see my updated answer. I think I read about what you're describing here https://medium.com/@michal.bock/fix-weird-exceptions-when-running-django-tests-f58def71b59a but I'm importing the model directly. Would the approach I show above still produce this error?

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? I have same issue and have zero idea what is going on.